# Shared memory lib compatible with linux and windows c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, shared-memory

I'm looking for a shared memory lib that can handle both linux and windows platforms. I want to use it by C++.
Please let me know if you know any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [boost shared memory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) - this is cross platform.